How to Embed Custom ANPR Software Developed with Python on an IP Camera?
I’m working on a project where I need to implement an Automatic Number Plate Recognition (ANPR) system. My goal is to embed my custom ANPR software, which I wrote in Python, directly onto an IP camera without using an external processor. The camera should be able to process images and recognize license plates independently.
One of the models from Hikvision that has this feature is: https://www.hikvision.com/europe/products/IP-Products/Network-Cameras/DeepinView-Series/DS-2CD7A26G0-P-IZ-H-S/
However, it is too expensive, and I want to achieve the same result with a lower-priced camera such as this: https://www.hikvision.com/en/products/IP-Products/Network-Cameras/value-series/ds-2cd1643g0-i-z-/
Can this camera handle the job I want to do?
Is it possible to do that? What specific features or specifications should I look for in an IP camera to ensure it can run custom ANPR software?
I am open to any suggestions. Thank you for your responses.
I made many research both with ChatGPT and Google, yet I could not find a proper answer. From my understanding, the processor in Hikvision DeepinView cameras is powerful enough to handle tasks such as image processing (especially car plate recognition). It appears that I can upload my own Python code using Hikvision’s SDK. However, as I mentioned before, it is above my price range and already has an embedded plate recognition feature, which I do not want because I want to implement it myself.
My main concern is whether the processor in the DS-2CD1643G0-I(Z) can handle my Python code and execute the car plate recognition tasks as it would on a computer. Additionally, I do not want to use any external processor like a Raspberry Pi, so my only option is to use the internal processor in the security camera.
